# Comparing multiple strings in while loop

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison

I'm a beginner just trying to make a simple calculator that prompts the user for an two values and an operand.

```
string operand;
cin >> operand;
while (operand != "+") || (operand != "-") || (operand !=  "*")|| (operand != "/"))
{
    cout << "operand must be either'+', '-', '*', or '/'." << endl;
    cin >> operand;
}
```

Why does it keep entering the while loop no matter what I input into operand?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `&&` not `||`

```
while ((operand != "+") && (operand != "-") && (operand !=  "*") && (operand != "/"))
```

Answer (score 1):

use [std::string::find_first_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)

```
while (operand.find_first_of("+-*/") == std::string::npos)
{
   //...
}
```